# Compare only time difference in Date objects

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have two `Date` objects and I want to compare only the time difference between them, ignoring the date. 
Would be something like:

dt1 = (Date) 2016-09-22 20:05:01 UTC
dt2 = (Date) 2016-08-20 22:06:00 UTC

and the difference between dt1 and dt2 would be 2 hours or 121 minutes.

Is there a function in Swift that I could do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Calendar` to extract the `DateComponents` and then combine the day, month, and year from one with the hour, minute, and second of the other into another `Date` object. Then you can compare the two `Date` objects that share the same date using the well documented methods.

For example, given `date1` and `date2`, we can calculate `date3` with date of `date1`, but time of `date2`. We can then compare `date1` to this new `date3`:

```
let calendar = Calendar.current
let components2 = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: date2)
let date3 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: components2.hour!, minute: components2.minute!, second: components2.second!, of: date1)!
```

Then, to get the number of minutes between `date1` and `date3`:

```
let minutes = calendar.dateComponents([.minute], from: date1, to: date3).minute!
```

Or hours and minutes:

```
let difference = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute], from: date1, to: date3)
let hours = difference.hour!
let minutes = difference.minute!
```

Or, if you want to show this to the user, you'd often use `DateComponentsFormatter` to get a nice, localized string representation:

```
let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
formatter.unitsStyle = .full
formatter.allowedUnits = [.hour, .minute]  // or [.minute]
let string = formatter.string(from: date1, to: date3)!
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring the date, You can use [timeIntervalSince(date:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdate/1410206-timeintervalsince) to get the number of seconds between two dates.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSCalenar`, then find out the hour, minute land then find the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 3 Extention for comparing Time Only**

```
import UIKit

extension Date {
    func compareTimeOnly(to: Date) -> ComparisonResult {
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let components2 = calendar.dateComponents([.hour, .minute, .second], from: to)
    let date3 = calendar.date(bySettingHour: components2.hour!, minute: components2.minute!, second: components2.second!, of: self)!

    let seconds = calendar.dateComponents([.second], from: self, to: date3).second!
    if seconds == 0 {
        return .orderedSame
    } else if seconds > 0 {
        // Ascending means before
        return .orderedAscending
    } else {
        // Descending means after
        return .orderedDescending
    }
    }
}
```

**Some Tests**

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

let date1 = Date()
var date2 = dateFormatter.date(from: "2016-12-26T12:12:12")!

let result = date1.compareTimeOnly(to: date2)
print(result.rawValue)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func findsecond(s_date:String,e_date:String) -> Int {
    //set date formate

    let Dateformatter = DateFormatter()

    Dateformatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy h:mm a"

    //convert string to date

    let dateold = Dateformatter.date(from: start_date)!
    let datenew = Dateformatter.date(from: end_date)!
    //use default datecomponents with two dates
    let calendar1 = Calendar.current
    let components = calendar1.dateComponents([.second], from: dateold, to: datenew)
    let seconds = components.second
    print("Seconds: \(seconds)")
    return seconds!

}
```